# How to set Password must meet minimum requirements policy using command prompt

Tags: windows-10, command-line, powershell, passwords, group-policy

I need to set local password policy. I don't want to use gpedit.msc .I able to set all other policies using net accounts command but complexity requirements is not listing in net accounts. How can I change password complexity requirements using command line. If it is not possible can change it using powershell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a local account, you can use `net accounts` from the command line as stated [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/556003):

> The “Net Accounts” command is used to set the policy settings on local computer such as Account policies and password policies. This command can not be used on domain controller. This command is only used on local computer.

[Net accounts documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490698(v=technet.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

> Syntax
>
> net accounts [/forcelogoff:{minutes | no}] [/minpwlen:length] [/maxpwage:{days | unlimited}] [/minpwage:days] [/uniquepw:number] [/domain]

This [page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/set-addefaultdomainpasswordpolicy?view=win10-ps) from Microsoft describes how to use Powershell to setup the default domain password policy by using the `Set-ADDefaultDomainPasswordPolicy` of the Active Directory Module.

Use `ComplexityEnabled` property to enable/disable the password complexity.

> -ComplexityEnabled
>
> Specifies whether password complexity is enabled for the password policy. If enabled, the password must contain three of the following four character types:
>
> - Uppercase characters (A, B, C, D, E, ...)
> - Lowercase characters (a, b, c, d, e, ...)
> - Numerals (0, 1, 2, 3, ...)
> - Special characters (#, $, *, %, ...)
>
> This parameter sets the ComplexityEnabled property of a password policy. The acceptable values for this parameter are:
>
> - $False or 0. Disables password complexity.
> - $True or 1. Enables password complexity.

Comment: Thanks, can i change it using command line?

Comment: @Iceberg See edit.